# How to create a N = 1000 , 2 dimensional 2 classes dataset given mean = [-8,8]T, covariance = [ [0.3 1.5] [1.5 9.0] ]

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, covariance-matrix

Generate a 1000 two-dimensional dataset, X that is of two classes and plot. The 1
500 data vectors are modeled by the Gaussian distribution with mean, m1 = [­ 8, 8]
T
and the rest 500 data vectors are modeled by the Gaussian distribution with mean
m2 = [­ 8, 8] . The covariance matrix for both distributions are
T
S = [0.3 1.5 1.5 9.0 ]
Use the same prescription to generate another data 200 and create a test dataset X .

Comment: Can you show us the research you did before asking the question?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using [numpy.random.multivariate_normal](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.multivariate_normal.html) you can do that.
Using the info you provided, you can do something like:

```
mean = [8,8]
cov = [[0.3, 1.5], [1.5, 9.0]]
x, y = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, 200).T
```